# C# Multiple Solution file support for SONARQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using latest version of SONAR Qube and i want to know if it's possible to configure TWO Solution Files as part of Single sonar-project.properties.

```
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=project1.sln

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=project2.sln
```

Can someone help me find out the configuration details how to do it so i can configure it for my Windows based service project1 and Web project as project2 here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no because :

1. There is only one supported and accurate way to analyze a Visual Studio solution: by using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild
2. And this SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild has not been built to support the merge/aggregation of several Visual Studio solutions. One Visual Studio solution -> one project in SonarQube.

Comment: Is this one Visual Studio solution -> one project in SonarQube still the case in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sonarqube scanner for MSBuild to analyze the solutions. Here is the documentation:
 http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild-msbuildcompat

Between the begin and end step you could build your two solutions

Comment: If i use that then how do i pass other sonar-project.properties values ? **Example :
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/AutomationTestAssistantResults.trx AND sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=GeneratedReports/CoverageReport.xml**
Currently i am using Excute SonarQube Scanner from Jenkins Plugin. 
That actually read this Property file values from my Project's solution automatically. Will be same here too ?

Comment: You can also use a sonar-project.properties file for the other properties... or you add the properties to the msbuild scanner begin step